# ¿Cómo muestro una imagen sacada de una base de datos en un label de la librería tkinter?

Tags: python, imagen, tkinter, sqlite3, blob

soy nuevo en esto de programar y esta es mi primera pregunta en este foro. 
La cosa es que tengo una base de datos sqlite3 en la que uno de sus campos es de tipo BLOB y en el que guardo imágenes. Mi duda es cómo mostrar dichas imágenes en un widget label de tkinter.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
import tkinter
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk()
contenedor = tkinter.Frame(root, cursor="heart")

conexion = sqlite3.connect("BBDD")
puntero = conexion.cursor()

puntero.execute("SELECT IMAGEN FROM INSTRUMENTOS WHERE ID=1;")
v_foto = puntero.fetchone() 
img = Image.open(v_foto) # Falla aquí, porque una tupla no tiene el atributo read.
pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img))

imagen = tkinter.Label(contenedor, image=pic)
imagen.image(pic)
imagen.grid(row=1, column=0)

conexion.close()
root.mainloop()
```

Si alguien pudiera ilustrarme en la manera correcta de extraer una imagen de una base de datos y mostrarla en un widget de tipo label; estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a partir de la base de que guardas tu imagen en la BBDD de forma similar a esta:

```
with open(ruta_a_la_imagen, 'rb') as input_file:
    blob = input_file.read()
    sql = '''INSERT INTO INSTRUMENTOS (IMAGEN, ) VALUES(?, );'''
    conn.execute(sql, (sqlite3.Binary(blob), ))
```

si esto es correcto, unas cuantas observaciones:

- `fetchone` retorna una sola **tupla** si existe al menos una fila que cumpla la consulta o `None`. Debes indizar sobre ella para obtener la cadena binaria, por ejemplo, si el campo BLOB es la segunda columna:

  ```
  v_foto = puntero.fetchone()[1]
  ```
- Lo que recibes de la BD es una cadena de bytes, que no puedes pasar de forma directa a `Image.open`, lo que si puedes hacer es usar `io.BytesIO` para simular un archivo binario en memoria. También se podría usar `Image.frombytes`.
- Aunque no se si es solo que no copiaste estas filas en la pregunta, en el código que muestras no posicionas el `Frame` en la ventana principal mediante `grid/pack/place`. Esto hace que no se muestre tampoco el `Label`.
- `imagen.image` es un atributo de instancia, no un método de instancia. En todo caso debe ser `imagen.image = pic` y no `imagen.image(pic)`, no obstante ya le pasas la imagen en el inicializador de la clase, por lo que es redundante.

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
import io
import tkinter
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



root = tkinter.Tk()
contenedor = tkinter.Frame(root, cursor="heart")
contenedor.pack()

conexion = sqlite3.connect("BBDD")
puntero = conexion.cursor()

puntero.execute("SELECT IMAGEN FROM INSTRUMENTOS WHERE ID=1;")
row = puntero.fetchone()
puntero.close()
conexion.close()

if row is not None:
    v_foto = row[1] # Cambiar índice por la columna correcta en tu caso
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(v_foto))
    pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    imagen = tkinter.Label(contenedor, image=pic)
else:
    imagen = tkinter.Label(contenedor, text="Imágen no disponible",
                           height=20, width=40
                           )

imagen.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sí, es cierto que se me olvidó posicionar el frame. (hice un archivo nuevo con lo esencial para la pregunta; evidentemente cometiendo algunos errores). Tu explicación ha sido muy ilustrativa. Me has hecho comprender muy bien el asunto después de una larga pero infructuosa búsqueda en google.

Mil milones de gracias! me has sido de grandísima ayuda. En serio eres un crack!! 

Saludos